# How to transfer the list through the navigators to the screens and get back the events?

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

How to correctly transfer the list to the screens, through the navigators and get from the event screens, to edit the list with the root component?

This code does not work exactly in the part of transferring and returning data between App and screen components.

**File with parent element:**

*App.js*

```js
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; // 1.0.0-beta.21

import EditScreen from './Screens/EditScreen';
import MainScreenT1 from './Screens/MainScreenT1';
import MainScreenT2 from './Screens/MainScreenT2';

let groceries = [{loc: 0, text: 'Apples'},
            {loc: 1, text: 'Bananas'},
            {loc: 0, text: 'Oranges'},
            {loc: 0, text: 'Mandarins'},
            {loc: 1, text: 'Cucumbers'},
            {loc: 0, text: 'Tomatoes'},
            {loc: 1, text: 'Milk'},
            {loc: 1, text: 'Potato'},
            {loc: 0, text: 'Coffee'},
            {loc: 0, text: 'Sugar'},
            {loc: 1, text: 'Candies'},
            {loc: 1, text: 'Sausage'},
            {loc: 0, text: 'Bread'},
            {loc: 0, text: 'Butter'},
            {loc: 1, text: 'Meat'},
            {loc: 1, text: 'Whiskey'},]

export default class App extends React.Component {
   state = {grList: groceries}
   
   onAddGr = (nText) => {
     const {grList} = this.state
 
     this.setState({
       grList: [{loc:0, text:nText}, ...grList],
     })
     groceries = grList
   }
   
   onLeft = (index) => {
    let {grList} = this.state
    grList[index].loc = 1
    this.setState({
      grList
    })
    groceries = grList
  }
  
  onRight = (index) => {
    let {grList} = this.state
    grList[index].loc = 0
    this.setState({
      grList
    })
    groceries = grList
  }
  
   onRemoveGr = (index) => {
     const {grList} = this.state
     this.setState({
       grList: grList.filter((gr, i) => i !== index),
     })
   }
   
  render() {
    const MainNavigator = StackNavigator({
      Main: { screen: TabNavigator({
        Tab1: { screen: MainScreenT1 },
        Tab2: { screen: MainScreenT2 },
      }, {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        swipeEnabled: false,
        animationEnabled: false,
        tabBarOptions: {
          showIcon: true,
          showLabel: false,
          activeTintColor: '#000000',
          inactiveTintColor: '#A4A4A4',
          indicatorStyle:{ 
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
          },
          style: {
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
          },
        }
      }
      )},
      Edit: { screen: EditScreen },
    },{
      navigationOptions: { header: false },
    })

    return (
      <MainNavigator
        grList={this.state}
        onSwipeLeftItemM ={this.onLeft} 
        onSwipeRightItemM = {this.onRight}
        onAddGrM = {this.onAddGr}
        onRemoveGrM = {this.onRemoveGr}
      />
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App)
```

**All three screens are similar in general:**

*EditScreen.js*

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, } from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal' // 5.0.0


import Input from '../Components/Input'
import DellList from '../Components/DellList'

class EditScreen extends React.Component {
    state = {
     isModalVisible: false
   }
 
   _showModal = () => this.setState({ isModalVisible: true })
 
   _hideModal = () => this.setState({ isModalVisible: false })
   
   render() {
    const {grList} = this.props
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
     
    const {onAddGrM} = this.props
    const {onRemoveGrM} = this.props
    
    return (
      <View style={styles.back}>
         <View style={{ height: 25,}} />
         
         <View style={styles.topPanel}>
           <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cell} onPress={this._showModal}>
             <Text style={styles.headText} > + </Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
           <View style={{flex: 2, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
             <Text style={styles.headText}> Groceries </Text>
           </View>
           <TouchableOpacity style={styles.cell} onPress={() => navigate('Main')}>
             <Text style={styles.headText}> Done </Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
         
         <View style={{flex: 1}}>
           <DellList 
           list={grList}
           onPressItem= { (index) => {onRemoveGrM(index)}}
           />
         </View>
         
         <Modal isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible} style={styles.forModal}>
           <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
             <Input
               placeholder={'Type here, then hit enter!'}
               onSubmitEditing={ (text) => {onAddGrM(text)}}
               onCancel={this._hideModal}
             />
           </View>
         </Modal>
       </View>
     );
   }
 }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  back: {
    backgroundColor: '#E5E5E5',
    flex: 1,
  },
  forModal: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  topPanel: {
    marginBottom: 1,
    height: 50,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  headText: {
    marginTop: 15,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  cell: {
    flex: 1, 
    height: 50, 
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
});

export default EditScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with updating variables and passing them around screens. I kept bumping into advices that redux would solve it. I took a look at redux and then started messing around with my data and trying to update and passing it around.
When I actually took the time to learn redux my problem was solved quite quickly. 
At least take the time to look at the tutorial by Dan Abramov (the creator of the project) and give it a go. [Link to page](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux)

Comment: Thank you. I have been trying for some time to solve it in different ways. And first of all with the use of Redux. But, I ran into a number of problems. For example, this code just does not work: http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/redux
I tried to implement it on https://snack.expo.io
Now I'm thinking of trying this:
https://medium.com/@sumitkushwaha/syncing-redux-store-with-asyncstorage-in-react-native-2b8b890b9ca1

There is still the decision to save data.

Comment: Redux is quite hard to get in the beginning. But if you look through the tutorial by Dan. Saving with Asyncstorage could solve the issue without. But sooner or later you will have to learn Redux. In the end it really makes life a lat easier. You could look into my repos at git if you wanna get an understanging. [Counter example](https://github.com/simjoh/react-native-redux-counter)

Comment: Yes, Redux is really not a simple technology. I will definitely look at your examples.